# How can I quickly delete many old Pipeline Job builds on a Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins server which has a lot of used space seemingly for no reason at all. After digging around I noticed that old builds were not being discarded for branches that are kept around (`master` for example). I can fix all the projects by adding a "keep x builds" setting, but I have a lot of projects and I need to clean up the disk straight away.

It's cumbersome and time consuming to manually delete jobs on a Jenkins server, and it is not clear how to proceed if you quickly need to free up some space (except for manually deleting stuff from the hard drive). Deleting stuff from the Jenkins `job` directory is probably going to leave some cruft in the `fingerprints` directory too(?) - not a good idea.

How can I quickly clean up a bunch of projects while still leaving say 5 builds per branch in a Pipeline project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have good news - I found a page describing build cleanup on the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Manually+run+log+rotation+on+all+jobs), but it doesn't cover Pipeline Jobs. Also it times out if you have a lot of projects.

I managed to create a new script based on the old one which handles timeout (but you will have to run it multiple times, probably).

Paste this in the `Script Console` under `Manage Jenkins`, found in the `Tools and Actions` section:

```
// Inspired by https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Manually+run+log+rotation+on+all+jobs
// Check out these files for more info on LogRotator and WorkflowJob
// https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/LogRotator.java
// https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.java
import hudson.tasks.*;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.*;

def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(WorkflowJob.class);
def numJobsToKeep = 5;
def rotator = new LogRotator(-1, numJobsToKeep);

def startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (WorkflowJob job : jobs) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 20000) {
        // Bail out if it takes too long, just run the script again until it feels "instant"
        break;
    }
    rotator.perform(job);
}
```

It freed up 50+ GB of cruft on my machine!

I would also recommend to set up some sort of global build discarder to make sure this does not happen again. [CloudBees has a good guide](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds).